# Embdedded CPPCMS - synchronous polling

Tags: embedded, polling, cppcms

In an embedded environment, I have an unavoidable polling requirement - checking state of an I2C device.

Is there an easy way to have it done within the CPPCMS service loop? The alternative design would be a separate process communicating with the CPPCMS service asynchronously - but there are advantages of having it in a shared application.

I'd like to schedule a callback every 200ms, for instance.

Comment: That framework does not look like suitable for embedded devices..

Comment: cppcms has especially been designed for embedded devices and supports both synchronous and asynchronous polling. Without more information on what you have already tried to do (code and what didn't work as you would have expected), I can only refer you to the official documentation and to the official cppcms mailing list where Artyom, cppcms's lead developer, actively replies to support requests.

Comment: I see nothing [here](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main) that suggests its use in embedded systems (or even its relevance to I2C - am I missing something?).  Moreover it has a number of dependencies such as a POSIX runtime and Boost libraries; that already precludes a large number of embedded systems.  Embedded systems already capable of running Linux perhaps - but that is a tiny subset of all embedded systems and not mentioned in teh tags.

Comment: I2C is a very simple physical layer protocol why would you deploy an apparently unrelated framework just for that?  What is the platform?  What are the memory and performance constraints?  cppCMS has a number of dependencies that make it unsuited to most embedded systems. If your target is running Linux you should really state that because that is a minority of embedded systems and by no means a given.

Comment: @Clifford The exact quote is "Embedded underpowered devices -- CppCMS allows the creation of rich applications with reasonably fast perfomance on relatively low cost hardware" found [here](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/when_to_use_cppcms)

Comment: @pajeet : a year in, I hardly care, but my other points apply, and any platform that supports Linux is in the higher end of embedded systems.